# Horizontal scroll - page is smaller than the screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 pages and trying to scroll them horizontally. But the page width is not spanning across. Page 2 is visible. How to fix this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8WVe/

HTML:

```
<section class="section span12" id="section1">
        <header>
            <div class="main-header">
                <a href="#" alt="My Logo"><span class="get">My Logo</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="content-wrapper span10">
            <div class="sub-headline span8">
                <h2>sfdhgsafdhasgh</h2>
                <small>dshgfgdsjhgfgfjhdgsfdjgdf</small>
            </div>
            <div class="inner span8">
                <p>
                    ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn" id="click" alt="click" aria-label="click" tab-index="-1">Click</a>
            </div>
            <a class="nav-slide next" href="#section2">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="section span12" id="section2">
        <header>
            <div class="main-header">
                <a href="#" alt="My Logo">My Logo</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="content-wrapper span10">
            <div class="sub-headline span8">
                <h2>sfdhgsafdhasgh</h2>
                <small>dshgfgdsjhgfgfjhdgsfdjgdf</small>
            </div>
            <div class="inner span8">
                <p>
                    ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>ewtytrfjwhbfhshgfeyjrgf<br>
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn" id="click" alt="click" aria-label="click" tab-index="-1">Click</a>
            </div>
            <a class="nav-slide prev" href="#section2">&lsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    width:12000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}

/*Page Styles*/

/*header*/
header {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 7%;
}


.section{
    margin:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #f0f0f0;
}
.section h2{
    margin:50px 0px 30px 50px;
}
.section p{
    margin:20px 0px 0px 50px;
    width:600px;
}



.section#section1 {
    background-color: #48a95e;
}
.section#section2{
    background-color: #C6FFC8;
}
.section ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:20px 0px 0px 550px;
}
.content-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Slide Nav Button*/
.nav-slide {
    position: relative;
    top: 13%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.prev {
    float: left;
}
.next {
    float: right;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
                $('a.next').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);
                    /*
                    if you want to use one of the easing effects:
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                     */
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                    }, 1000);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                $('a.prev').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                    }, 1000);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

Comment: Are you trying to force each page to fill the screen regardless of width?

Comment: Yes. Page should fill the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OPeSIqE/2/)**
(**just fill with content and you're done**)

**JS:**

```
var c = 0, winW = 0;

$('.btn').click(function(){ 
  winW = $(window).width();
  c = +$(this).hasClass('next'); // 1 , 0
  $('#overflowSections').stop().animate({scrollLeft: winW*c}, 2000); 
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  winW = $(this).width();
  $('#overflowSections').scrollLeft(winW*c);
});
```

**BASIC HTML:**

```
<div id="overflowSections">

  <section id="section1">
     <div class="content">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Content 2...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn next">NEXT</div>
  </section>


  <section id="section2">   
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Content 2...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn prev">PREV</div>
  </section>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#overflowSections{
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0; /* !! WARNING !! */
}

section{
  font-size:16px; /* !! RESET !! */
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
section .content{
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
#section1{
  background:#48A95E;
}
#section2{
  background:#C6FFC8;
}
.btn{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  padding:20px 30px;
  background:#fff;
  opacity:0.7;
}
.next{
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had one issue thou' when I added this to a new html page, on loading I don't see the "next" button on the screen. I've to scoll to see it. Once I click "Prev" then it works fine.

Comment: @dragonfly probably on page load you need to reset the scrollLeft `$('#overflowSections').scrollLeft(0)` otherwise might be memorized by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a relative width of 200% for the body in order to make it twice the size of the window and then make each section half the size of the body :

```
body{
    width:200%;
}

.section{
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your links are animating `scrollLeft` to `$(this.href).offset().left`.  This works ok for the first link but the second one has already been scrolled to its own position.

To remedy this, don't reference the link locations but instead, the locations of each section.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8WVe/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $('a.next').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $goNext = $(this).parents('section').next('section');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $goNext.offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('a.prev').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $goBack = $(this).parents('section').prev('section');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $goBack.offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

EDIT:  Combined to one function -

```
$(function () {
    $('.nav-slide').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $goHere = ($(this).hasClass('next')) ? $(this).parents('section').next('section') : $(this).parents('section').prev('section');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $goHere.offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pkp7/) with condensed code (and some corrected HTML).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only these two `.section`s you could easially use the half of the total width:

```
.section{
    margin:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #f0f0f0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8WVe/3/)**

However when you want to let this do automatic, for example when you will add more then 2 `.section`s you can do this with jQuery:

```
var width = $('body').outerWidth() / $('.section').length;

$('.section').css('width', width);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8WVe/1/)**